# How to have two sets of shortcut keys for Compiz grid commands "Put Left" and "Put Right"?

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys

I would like to have two shortcuts each for "Put Left" and "Put Right" for positioning windows in the left and right position.

Specifically, I would like the default keys as well as some custom keys that are more accessible when typing:

i.e.:

- Put Left: `<Control><Alt>KP4` and `<Shift><Alt>H`
- Put Right: `<Control><Alt>KP6` and `<Shift><Alt>L`

The CompizConfig dialogue box appears to only allow one shortcut key to be assigned.

**How can I have two shortcut keys enabled for a single grid compiz-config setting?**

Comment: Is there any option in ccsm to type in the command rather than the GUI option?

Comment: I just found out that this will not work if you log in with Ubuntu 2D. Greetings!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do it is simply map the custom secondary keyboard shortcut to the primary (Compiz) shortcut using `xdotool`.

1. *xdotool* is a small command-line utility which allows automation of keyboard and mouse clicks/movements; install it with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`
2. We'll assume here that the default shortcuts for Grid Left/Right are as below: (`Ctrl+Super+Left/Right`):

   [image]
3. Open Settings...Keyboard, and go to the Shortcuts tab. Click `+` to create a custom shortcut, naming it say *Compiz GridRightAlt*, and setting the "Command" field to:

   ```
   xdotool key --clearmodifiers Ctrl+Super+Right
   ```

   Click Apply. The right-column will say *Disabled*, click on it and you'll see "New Accelerator": press your shortcut key combo, e.g. `Shift+Alt+L`.

   [image]

   - Repeat the steps for the left *Compiz GridLeftAlt*, setting the command to:

   ```
   xdotool key --clearmodifiers Ctrl+Super+Left
   ```

   and the shortcut keycombo to `Shift+Alt+H`.

Close the Keyboard settings and that's it!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell compiz will only allow one keybind as you noticed.

However with a tiny bit of work you can get around this limitation!

First install `pycompiz` found [here](http://code.google.com/p/pycompiz). If you have `svn` you can do this using

```
svn checkout http://pycompiz.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ pycompiz-read-only
```

Install after navigating into the projects folder,

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Next create these two tiny python scripts, and place them in your `~/bin` folder. 
Then either make them executable (`chmod u+x FILENAME`) or when setting the keybindings use `python SCRIPTNAME`.

file: putleft

```
#/usr/bin/python 
import compiz
compiz.call('grid', 'put_left')
```

file: putright

```
#/usr/bin/python 
import compiz
compiz.call('grid', 'put_right')
```

Lastly you can create two custom command shortcuts for each of these scripts in the custom commands section of the compiz config (ccsm), and hey presto - two keybinds to achieve the same effect. As mentioned above, if you made the scripts executable, the commands will be `putleft` and `putright`, else they will be `python ~/bin/putleft` and `python ~/bin/putright`.

Enjoy!